# python cmake/boost can't find boost libraries

Tags: boost, cmake, boost-python

I try to compile the [Frechet-CUDA](https://github.com/StefanMeintrup/Frechet-CUDA) package for python. I installed C++ via Visual Studio and installed dlib and cmake for python to compile the package. Furthermore added boost 3.18.

Still get the following error: Cmake 3.24 is unable to to find the boost components 'system chrono program_options python3 numpy3'. The complete stacktrace with `BOOST_DEBUG=On` looks like this:

```
C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\_distutils_hack\__init__.py:19: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools, but 
importing Setuptools also replaces the `distutils` module in `sys.modules`. This may lead to undesirable behaviors or errors. To avoid these issues, avoid using distutils directly, ensure that setuptools is installed in the traditional way (e.g. not an editable install), and/or make sure that setuptools is always imported before distutils.
  "Distutils was imported before Setuptools, but importing Setuptools " 
C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\_distutils_hack\__init__.py:33: UserWarning: Setuptools is replacing distutils.
  warnings.warn("Setuptools is replacing distutils.")
running install
C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\command\install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\command\easy_install.py:147: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.      
  EasyInstallDeprecationWarning,
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing Frechet_CUDA.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to Frechet_CUDA.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to Frechet_CUDA.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'Frechet_CUDA.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'Frechet_CUDA.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_ext
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.19043.
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1689 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = <unset>
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1690 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = "TRUE"
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1691 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = <unset>
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1692 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = <unset>
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1693 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = <unset>
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1694 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = <unset>
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1726 ] BOOST_ROOT = "C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0"
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1727 ] ENV{BOOST_ROOT} = <unset>
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1728 ] BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = <unset>
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1729 ] ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} = <unset>
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1730 ] BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = <unset>
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1731 ] ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} = <unset>
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1819 ] location of version.hpp: C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/boost/version.hpp
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1859 ] Boost_VERSION = "108000"
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1860 ] Boost_VERSION_STRING = "1.80.0"
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1861 ] Boost_VERSION_MACRO = "108000"
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1862 ] Boost_VERSION_MAJOR = "1"
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1863 ] Boost_VERSION_MINOR = "80"
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1864 ] Boost_VERSION_PATCH = "0"
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1865 ] Boost_VERSION_COUNT = "3"
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1889 ] Boost_LIB_PREFIX = ""
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1890 ] Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:953 ] _boost_COMPILER = "-vc143;-vc142;-vc141;-vc140" (guessed)
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1926 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = "-mt"
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2004 ] _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "-x64" (detected)
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2008 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-"
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2009 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-gd"
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2069 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/lib;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/stage/lib;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/lib;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/../lib;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/stage/lib;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/../lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/../lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/../lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/../lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.0;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2070 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/lib;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/stage/lib;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/lib;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/../lib;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/stage/lib;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/../lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/../lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/../lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/../lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.0;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
CMake Warning at C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1384 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1507 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2118 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package)


CMake Warning at C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1384 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1507 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2118 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package)


CMake Warning at C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1384 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1507 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2118 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package)


CMake Warning at C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1384 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1507 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2118 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package)


CMake Warning at C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1384 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1507 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2118 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package)


-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2255 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-vc143-mt-x64-1_80;boost_system-vc143-mt-x64;boost_system-vc143-mt;boost_system-vc142-mt-x64-1_80;boost_system-vc142-mt-x64;boost_system-vc142-mt;boost_system-vc141-mt-x64-1_80;boost_system-vc141-mt-x64;boost_system-vc141-mt;boost_system-vc140-mt-x64-1_80;boost_system-vc140-mt-x64;boost_system-vc140-mt;boost_system-mt-x64-1_80;boost_system-mt-x64;boost_system-mt;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2310 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_system-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_system-vc143-mt-gd-x64;boost_system-vc143-mt-gd;boost_system-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_system-vc142-mt-gd-x64;boost_system-vc142-mt-gd;boost_system-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_system-vc141-mt-gd-x64;boost_system-vc141-mt-gd;boost_system-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_system-vc140-mt-gd-x64;boost_system-vc140-mt-gd;boost_system-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_system-mt-gd-x64;boost_system-mt-gd;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2255 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_chrono-vc143-mt-x64-1_80;boost_chrono-vc143-mt-x64;boost_chrono-vc143-mt;boost_chrono-vc142-mt-x64-1_80;boost_chrono-vc142-mt-x64;boost_chrono-vc142-mt;boost_chrono-vc141-mt-x64-1_80;boost_chrono-vc141-mt-x64;boost_chrono-vc141-mt;boost_chrono-vc140-mt-x64-1_80;boost_chrono-vc140-mt-x64;boost_chrono-vc140-mt;boost_chrono-mt-x64-1_80;boost_chrono-mt-x64;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2310 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_chrono-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_chrono-vc143-mt-gd-x64;boost_chrono-vc143-mt-gd;boost_chrono-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_chrono-vc142-mt-gd-x64;boost_chrono-vc142-mt-gd;boost_chrono-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_chrono-vc141-mt-gd-x64;boost_chrono-vc141-mt-gd;boost_chrono-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_chrono-vc140-mt-gd-x64;boost_chrono-vc140-mt-gd;boost_chrono-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_chrono-mt-gd-x64;boost_chrono-mt-gd;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2255 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_program_options-vc143-mt-x64-1_80;boost_program_options-vc143-mt-x64;boost_program_options-vc143-mt;boost_program_options-vc142-mt-x64-1_80;boost_program_options-vc142-mt-x64;boost_program_options-vc142-mt;boost_program_options-vc141-mt-x64-1_80;boost_program_options-vc141-mt-x64;boost_program_options-vc141-mt;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-x64-1_80;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-x64;boost_program_options-vc140-mt;boost_program_options-mt-x64-1_80;boost_program_options-mt-x64;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2310 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_program_options-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_program_options-vc143-mt-gd-x64;boost_program_options-vc143-mt-gd;boost_program_options-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_program_options-vc142-mt-gd-x64;boost_program_options-vc142-mt-gd;boost_program_options-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_program_options-vc141-mt-gd-x64;boost_program_options-vc141-mt-gd;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-gd-x64;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-gd;boost_program_options-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_program_options-mt-gd-x64;boost_program_options-mt-gd;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options     
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2195 ] Component-specific library search names for : python3
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2255 ] Searching for PYTHON3_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_python3-vc143-mt-x64-1_80;boost_python3-vc143-mt-x64;boost_python3-vc143-mt;boost_python3-vc142-mt-x64-1_80;boost_python3-vc142-mt-x64;boost_python3-vc142-mt;boost_python3-vc141-mt-x64-1_80;boost_python3-vc141-mt-x64;boost_python3-vc141-mt;boost_python3-vc140-mt-x64-1_80;boost_python3-vc140-mt-x64;boost_python3-vc140-mt;boost_python3-mt-x64-1_80;boost_python3-mt-x64;boost_python3-mt;boost_python3-mt;boost_python3;boost_python3-vc143-mt-x64-1_80;boost_python3-vc143-mt-x64;boost_python3-vc143-mt;boost_python3-vc142-mt-x64-1_80;boost_python3-vc142-mt-x64;boost_python3-vc142-mt;boost_python3-vc141-mt-x64-1_80;boost_python3-vc141-mt-x64;boost_python3-vc141-mt;boost_python3-vc140-mt-x64-1_80;boost_python3-vc140-mt-x64;boost_python3-vc140-mt;boost_python3-mt-x64-1_80;boost_python3-mt-x64;boost_python3-mt;boost_python3-mt;boost_python3
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2310 ] Searching for PYTHON3_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_python3-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_python3-vc143-mt-gd-x64;boost_python3-vc143-mt-gd;boost_python3-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_python3-vc142-mt-gd-x64;boost_python3-vc142-mt-gd;boost_python3-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_python3-vc141-mt-gd-x64;boost_python3-vc141-mt-gd;boost_python3-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_python3-vc140-mt-gd-x64;boost_python3-vc140-mt-gd;boost_python3-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_python3-mt-gd-x64;boost_python3-mt-gd;boost_python3-mt;boost_python3;boost_python3-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_python3-vc143-mt-gd-x64;boost_python3-vc143-mt-gd;boost_python3-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_python3-vc142-mt-gd-x64;boost_python3-vc142-mt-gd;boost_python3-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_python3-vc141-mt-gd-x64;boost_python3-vc141-mt-gd;boost_python3-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_python3-vc140-mt-gd-x64;boost_python3-vc140-mt-gd;boost_python3-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_python3-mt-gd-x64;boost_python3-mt-gd;boost_python3-mt;boost_python3
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2195 ] Component-specific library search names for : numpy3
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2255 ] Searching for NUMPY3_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_numpy3-vc143-mt-x64-1_80;boost_numpy3-vc143-mt-x64;boost_numpy3-vc143-mt;boost_numpy3-vc142-mt-x64-1_80;boost_numpy3-vc142-mt-x64;boost_numpy3-vc142-mt;boost_numpy3-vc141-mt-x64-1_80;boost_numpy3-vc141-mt-x64;boost_numpy3-vc141-mt;boost_numpy3-vc140-mt-x64-1_80;boost_numpy3-vc140-mt-x64;boost_numpy3-vc140-mt;boost_numpy3-mt-x64-1_80;boost_numpy3-mt-x64;boost_numpy3-mt;boost_numpy3-mt;boost_numpy3;boost_numpy3-vc143-mt-x64-1_80;boost_numpy3-vc143-mt-x64;boost_numpy3-vc143-mt;boost_numpy3-vc142-mt-x64-1_80;boost_numpy3-vc142-mt-x64;boost_numpy3-vc142-mt;boost_numpy3-vc141-mt-x64-1_80;boost_numpy3-vc141-mt-x64;boost_numpy3-vc141-mt;boost_numpy3-vc140-mt-x64-1_80;boost_numpy3-vc140-mt-x64;boost_numpy3-vc140-mt;boost_numpy3-mt-x64-1_80;boost_numpy3-mt-x64;boost_numpy3-mt;boost_numpy3-mt;boost_numpy3
-- [ C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2310 ] Searching for NUMPY3_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_numpy3-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_numpy3-vc143-mt-gd-x64;boost_numpy3-vc143-mt-gd;boost_numpy3-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_numpy3-vc142-mt-gd-x64;boost_numpy3-vc142-mt-gd;boost_numpy3-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_numpy3-vc141-mt-gd-x64;boost_numpy3-vc141-mt-gd;boost_numpy3-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_numpy3-vc140-mt-gd-x64;boost_numpy3-vc140-mt-gd;boost_numpy3-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_numpy3-mt-gd-x64;boost_numpy3-mt-gd;boost_numpy3-mt;boost_numpy3;boost_numpy3-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_numpy3-vc143-mt-gd-x64;boost_numpy3-vc143-mt-gd;boost_numpy3-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_numpy3-vc142-mt-gd-x64;boost_numpy3-vc142-mt-gd;boost_numpy3-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_numpy3-vc141-mt-gd-x64;boost_numpy3-vc141-mt-gd;boost_numpy3-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_numpy3-vc140-mt-gd-x64;boost_numpy3-vc140-mt-gd;boost_numpy3-mt-gd-x64-1_80;boost_numpy3-mt-gd-x64;boost_numpy3-mt-gd;boost_numpy3-mt;boost_numpy3    
CMake Error at C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: system chrono program_options python3
  numpy3) (found suitable version "1.80.0", minimum required is "1.80") 
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2376 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Anwender/Documents/GitHub/some_project/py/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-37/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".     
See also "C:/Users/Anwender/Documents/GitHub/some_project/py/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-37/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 81, in <module>
    zip_safe=False,
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
    return run_commands(dist)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 973, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 992, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\command\install.py", line 74, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\command\install.py", line 123, in do_egg_install
    self.run_command('bdist_egg')
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 992, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 165, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 151, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 992, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
    self.build()
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 112, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 992, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 35, in run
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "setup.py", line 64, in build_extension
    cwd=self.build_temp, env=env)
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 328, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Anwender\\Documents\\GitHub\\some_project\\py/..', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Anwender\\Documents\\GitHub\\some_project\\py\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\Anwender\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Anwender\\Documents\\GitHub\\some_project\\py\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I added `set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_80_0/libs)` to the CMakeList.txt since most of the components in question (still missing python3 and numpy3) are located in this folder.

Question: What does CMake need to recognize the boost components in question?

EDIT I: The CMakeList.txt looks like the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(frechet_cuda LANGUAGES CUDA CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fopenmp")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fpermissive") #supress error in older gcc
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Ofast")
set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} --ptxas-options=-v")
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -O3 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50;-rdc=true;-use_fast_math")

enable_language(CUDA)

if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD)
    set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 11)
    set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
endif()
# Include header files from directory 'include'
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

find_package(PythonInterp REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
set(BOOST_ROOT C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_79_0/)
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS C:/Users/Anwender/AppData/Local/boost_1_79_0/libs)
set(Boost_DEBUG ON)
find_package(Boost 1.79 COMPONENTS system chrono program_options python3 numpy3 REQUIRED)
find_package(CUDA  REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${install_dir}/include)
link_libraries(${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${DLIB_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})
add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL)

PYTHON_ADD_MODULE(frechet_cuda
        src/compute_distance_wrapper.cpp 
        src/curve.cpp 
        src/geometry_basics.cpp
        src/frechet.cpp
        src/intersection_algorithm_in_parallel.cu
)
```

EDIT II:
overview of the filesystem `system` in my boost folder (path= C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\boost_1_79_0\boost)

The result can be seen [here](https://codefile.io/f/V6BJABWCzbtry5YYjWoV) (Output would be too long for the body) tl;dr: I cant see such file as described in the `SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE`.

How can I get those files and where to put them?

Comment: The line `Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE` describes which exact file names are tried when search `system` library. Do you have any of these files in your Boost installation? If yes, then what is **exact path** of that existing file?

Comment: It seems that under directory `C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\boost_1_79_0\boost` you have Boost **sources** (compare content with https://github.com/boostorg/boost). For use the Boost library you need to **install** it.

Comment: I installed it and still this procedure for this MakeFile failed. In the end I installed this package https://github.com/derohde/Fred#installation instead.